# collect different types of class and call their methods in c++

Tags: c++, templates

Is there any way in C++ to collect different types of classes and call their methods?
What I want to do is as below,

```
template<namespace T>
class A
{
    A method_A1(T a)
    {
        ...
    }

    void method_A2(int aa)
    {
        ...
    }

        ...
};

class B
{
    ...
};

class C
{
    ...
};

class D
{
    ...
};

A<B> *b;
A<C> *c;
A<D> *d;

b -> method_A2(3);
c -> method_A2(5);
```

In this code object b,c,d they are totally different object, right? Not related.
But I want to bind them with a array, so...

```
z[0] = b;
z[1] = c;
z[2] = d;
```

like this. 
I found some solutions, however the solutions are only for collecting different types. (using void* arrays or vectors for inherited objects) I also wanna access to their methods.

```
z[0] -> method_A2(3);
z[1] -> method_A3(5);
```

like this.
In this case how should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How would the compiler know that z[0] has method_A2 unless z is an array of objects that all have method_A2? There's no way to do this in C++ without a common interface between the classes.

Comment: If the function `method_A1` didn't use the template type you could have added a base class with pure virtual functions that `A` would inherit from.

Comment: The closest you can get with standard C++ is a [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple). But everything needs to be _collected_ at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
typedef boost::variant<A<B>, A<C>, A<D>> AVariant;
std::array<AVariant, 3> z;

z[0] = *b;
z[1] = *c;
z[2] = *d;
```

Then you can inspect each element's type if needed, or "visit" them using `boost::static_visitor` as shown here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/variant.html

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use **inheritance** and **polymorphisms**. I have posted an example of what exactly can be a solution of your problem. See the `main` function:

```
#include <iostream>

class weapon {

 public:
  int fireRate;
  int bulletDamage;
  int range;
  int activeBullet;

 public:
  virtual void fire(void) {std::cout << "machine " << '\n';}
  virtual ~weapon() {std::cout << "destructor is virtual" << '\n';}
};

class machineGun: public weapon {
 public: 
  void fire(void) {std::cout << "machine gun firing" << '\n';}
  ~machineGun(void) { std::cout << "machine gun destroyed" << '\n';}
};

class flamer: public weapon {
 public: 
  void fire(void) {std::cout << "flamer firing" << '\n';}
  ~flamer(void) {std::cout << "flamer destroyed" << '\n';}
};

int main(void)
{
    const int count = 2;
    weapon *weapons[count];

    machineGun *a = new machineGun();
    flamer     *b = new flamer();

    weapons[0] = a;
    weapons[1] = b;

    weapons[0]->fire();
    weapons[1]->fire();

    delete a;
    delete b;

}
```

Comment: This does not work for the OP's case as the function signature in the derived class is different from the base class as it uses the template type.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change your classes' hierarchy, you can try having an array of callable objects. Something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <array>

class A
{
    public:
    void Foo(int a)
    {
        std::cout << "Foo " << a << std::endl;
    }
};

class B
{
    public:
    void Bar(int a)
    {
        std::cout << "Bar " << a << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
   using namespace std::placeholders;

   A a;
   B b;

   auto a_func = std::bind(&A::Foo, a, _1);
   auto b_func = std::bind(&B::Bar, b, _1);

   std::array<std::function<void(int)>, 2> arr = {
     std::bind(&A::Foo, a, _1),
     std::bind(&B::Bar, b, _1)
   };

   arr[0](1);
   arr[1](2);

   return 0;
}
```

BTW, this will only work if you use compiler with full C++11 support.